# How to deal with the appearance of delta functions in differential cross sections?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, dirac-delta-distributions, scattering-cross-section, fermis-golden-rule

I've recently started learning quantum field theory, and I'm on chapter 3 of Hatfield's *Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles and Strings*. I was flipping through the book today, and I came across an expression in chapter 7.8 for differential cross sections in elastic scattering. It roughly stated that $$d\sigma \propto \frac {d^3p_3}{(2\pi)^3 2p^0_3}\frac{d^3p_4}{(2\pi)^32p^0_4}\delta(p_1 +p_2-p_3-p_4),$$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the incoming momenta and $p_3$ and $p_4$ are the outgoing momenta. I understand that the delta function here implies that momentum is conserved, however, it presents an infinity in an otherwise measurable quantity. This seems similar to the situation with Fermi's golden rule in which the transition rate is $$\Gamma_{i\to f}=\frac {2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle f|V|i\rangle|^2\delta(E_f-E_i),$$ but this is expression is only meaningful when integrated against the density of final states $\int dE_f\rho(E_f)$, which thus gets rid of the infinity presented by the delta function. I am assuming that there is an analagous process that we do here, especially seeing as how the differential cross section can be defined as $$d\sigma =\frac{\Gamma_{i\to {d\Omega}}}{j_{inc}}$$ where $\Gamma_{i\to {d\Omega}}$ is the transition rate into final states with momentum pointing in the solid angle $d\Omega$. So the question is, how do we make the first expression above meaningful, i.e., get rid of the delta function so that the differential cross section is finite?

Comment: Why should the differential cross section be finite? It should be something you integrate over. And the delta function kills off some of the 6 spatial components of final momentum you are integrating over.

Comment: That's a good point, but why should it be infinite, if we define it using transition rates, which are finite (in general)?

Comment: It's not infinite after you integrate it. What it does is constrain the final states to lie on the submanifold of the 6 dimensional space that is consistent with the conservation law. The only way you can define a measure on a 6 dimensional space that is supported on a space of lower dimension is if you have something like a delta function that blows up on the submanifold.

Comment: After integrating it is not a differential cross section, but a total cross section. Am I mistaken about differential cross sections being measurable quantities?

Comment: You are used to a differential cross section that you integrate over solid angle parametrized by two angles, right? Well that's exactly what the delta function does for you. It kills off 4 of the 6 dimensions you are integrating over and you are left with a finite distribution living on a 2 dimensional space (solid angle).

Comment: So, upon killing the integrals with the delta function, the integrand is the (measurable) expression for the differential cross section?

Comment: Yes it sounds like you got it

Comment: Okay, great! Thanks for your patience with me and for helping me understand.